# Flutter: You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with an upload certificate that is not yet valid because it has been recently reset

Tags: android, flutter, apk, release, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to upload my Flutter App's appBundle file to PlayStore and creating a release for it.
I have set automatic zone and Clock for my PC and it would give a warning saying that the time stamp and current times don't match but it created the app bundle file for me anyway. then when i upload it to PlayStore it gives me this error

```
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with an upload certificate that is not yet valid because it has been recently reset. You will be able to upload APKs or Android App Bundles again from UTC
```

Then i tried to match my local PC date and time to the time stamp and the warning of them not matching stopped appearing while creating the bundle, but on playstore it still gives me the same message.

what did i do wrong/ how long should i wait?

Answer (score 0):

It just worked after 14+ hours

Answer (score 0):

When you reset your upload key, you always have to wait a certain amount of time before you can upload an APK or App Bundle again.